# crazy string in url problem

Tags: asp.net

I am working on asp.net 2.0.

Currently I started project that has been 80% developed by other.

when it comes to my hand there was no problem.

But suddenly I saw a problem in URL, e.g.

```
http://localhost:1281/MyProject/(S(tvrt5hnlt5tlwemdyjwrobjw))/Admin/WelcomeAdmin.aspx
```

so there is a crazy string between project Folder & subfolder or any subfile.

And it is amazing that it's not affecting My project.

But I want to know form where it comes and how? any guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's cookie-less sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178582.aspx).

Comment: I am doing it for maintaining it for setting timeout for 1 hour for admin and others will have 20 min. so if I remove it then will it work?
I am setting admin timeout by programmatically.

Comment: If you use the Session to store state, you need to have the sessionId stored somewhere.  If you are worried about browsers that will not allow cookies, you can use cookie-less.